# Codenameone: access sqlite outside application dir/database

Tags: codenameone

How can i Access a SQLite DB which exists outside the application/database dir?

Looks like `openOrCreate` alway point to the appdir/database

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `getDatabasePath` to get the path for the DB and assuming it is not null copy the file into the given location. The reasoning is that database might not be SQLite so it won't necessarily consist of one file. There is also the issue of filesystem which isn't very portable between platforms.

Comment: So if i had a sqlite database on external SD or any mounted usb drive, it is impossible to access these with [tag:codenameone]?

Comment: You'll need to copy the date locally and then open it. SD cards don't exist on iOS, Windows Phone and many newer Android devices so its not exactly portable.

Comment: You have a get roots method. The / file is only accessible in Android devices and will fail in iOS and most other devices.