# codenameone setURL with HTML file doesn't work on device

Tags: java, html, mobile, codenameone

i'm re writing an app with codename one for other devices other android.
On the simulator everything is working fine, iv'e got some buttons that, when pressed, give access to an HTML page, the actual code for this is:

```
 wifi.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            Form form = new Form("WiFi");
            Container container = new Container();

            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            container.addComponent(wb);
            wb.setURL("jar:///assets/html/wifi.html");

            System.out.println("url:"+wb.getURL());

            Command backCommand = new Command("Back") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                wifi.getComponentForm().showBack();
            }};

            form.addCommand(backCommand);
            form.setBackCommand(backCommand);
            form.addComponent(container);
            form.show();
        }
    });
```

When i first want to getURL() back, the string is empty; then when i want to build for an android device (Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3) when i tap on the button it returns me nothing but a blank page.
I also tried with an http link like https://www.google.com, on simulator no problem, on device the usual blank page.
Then i tried modifying the position of the html file, putting it in src like for the image file (that works on device), but still nothing.
I've checked the developer guide and every example i could find, and everyone got no problem with this (and on the simulator me neither). Could anyone solve this? 
Thank you :)

Comment: try to set the Form layout to BorderLayout and the container also to BorderLayout and add them to the center.

Comment: I tried like this, the simulator can't display the page, but on the device it gives me a brwoser error page (better than a blank page)

`Form form = new Form("WiFi");
                Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
                form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                                
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
                container.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,wb);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the file in the root of the src directory and point directly at it without the assets hierarchy for it to work properly across platforms.

Comment: i've tried like Chen said in the comment above with the borderlayouts, but still can't find my page `wb.setURL("/wifi.html");`

Comment: related question (path) on Database, i got an Sqlite .db file that should be pur in this folder \.cn1\database for the simulator to read, where should be put for the app to read? Everytime with Database.openOrCreate it is created because it can't find the file

Comment: Its a very different question. openOrCreate gets a name not a file name and you shouldn't use a file path. If you use a simple name it will be stored in the app home directory and shouldn't be recreated.

Comment: ok, but if i already got a file .db where should i put it? because if i use the .exists("filename.db")  method it returns me false, and the openOrCreate create a new empty file, with obviously cannot be queryed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140469/codenameone-access-sqlite-outside-application-dir-database

Comment: thanks, now i figured out that i have to open the .db file, then with input and output streams copy it to the correct path (after using openOrCreate), but i still got the problem of the inputstream path, infact it cannot read the file (FIleNotFoundException). My code is this `InputStream stream = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream("agenda.db");` agenda.db is in the /src directory, whould i put anywhere else?

Comment: Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream("/agenda.db", getClass());